# Where can I set Keycloak header experation time

Tags: flask, keycloak

When using flask_oidc and Keycloak to log in my app, 
I get a cookie with a header which expired an hour after it was issued.
This is caused my app to reload every hour and get a new cookie.

I tried to find out a solution both in Keycloak docs and in flask_oidc but didn't found one.

bellow you can find an example of the cookie header:

`{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "exp": 1562495222,
  "iat": 1562491622
}`

Am I missing some settings that I need to configure in order to stop my app to keep refreshing every hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in flask_oidc cookie_serializer, it turns out that it has an expiration of 1 hour by default to its cookies. 
I set it by adding longer expiration value to it constructor.

```
oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)
oidc.cookie_serializer = TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in=longer_value)
```

This was solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Keycloak token expiration? If so, you can do this in admin panel of keycloak:
Select proper realm, got to relam settings (on left menu) and than select the tab "tokens". There you can change validity of them.
Check the screenshot: [keycloak admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HhB0.png)

EDIT:
Based on the comment, I edited my comment...Your problem could also be in Flask settings. Please check this web page [flask-jwt](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html),where you can find also this:
JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES

```
How long an access token should live before it expires. This takes any value that can be safely added to a datetime.datetime object, including datetime.timedelta, dateutil.relativedelta, or an int (seconds), and defaults to 15 minutes. Can be set to False to disable expiration.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JureW , I set the Keycloak token expiration you mentioned, This was extended the id token expiration, but did not change the header expiration period. still having the issue :(